Need recommendations on my PCB
I’m designing my first 4-layer PCB for a 2-cell battery monitoring system using the BQ40Z50 BMS chip.

According to the datasheet, it’s recommended to create two separate grounds: one for the fuel gauge and one for the charger. I’ve implemented this separation, but I’m having trouble deciding how to attach them together properly.
Additionally, the power lines on this board need to handle currents ranging from 10A to 15A. Here’s a summary of my design and questions:
Current Stackup:
Top Layer: Signal/Power
Inner Layer 1: GND Plane
Inner Layer 2: GND Plane
Bottom Layer: Signal/Power
Key Concerns:
Ground Separation: How should I connect the separate grounds for the fuel gauge and charger to ensure proper functionality without introducing noise or other issues?
Power Trace Width: I need to confirm that my power trace width is sufficient for handling 10-15A. Should I consider increasing the copper thickness to 3 oz or 4 oz, or would it be better to implement double power lanes (one over another)? Any tools or calculators for determining the correct trace width would be greatly appreciated.
Thermal Management: Should I be using vias for better thermal management, or are there other recommendations for ensuring the board stays cool under high current? Are there any stackup adjustments or other considerations I might have missed?
Since this is my first 4-layer design, I’m sure there might be things I’m overlooking. Any advice or feedback on these issues would be very helpful. This my board.
Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Is there any reason why you wouldn't use via stitching to connect the GND planes? How much space do you have for your power traces? I've never had to use more than 2oz for that much current.

There is not much space for power traces but I made it 5mm wide. I thought to increase the thickness rather than width due to the space. Thank you, I will use via stitching.


Current Stackup

This stackup is good one thing you may want to consider is using the two inner planes with the same copper weight as PCB manufacturers typically build a core with symmetrical layers around it for the inner layers. One problem with inner layers is they don't dissipate heat as well with FR4 on either side.
As far as the PCB trace a 400mil inner trace trace @ 2oz (say 2" long) (remember it's the cross sectional area, so if you make it taller you can make the trace less wide) is sufficient for the conductor to be 20C temp rise over ambient.
A 200mil  2oz wide trace will give you a ~45C rise over ambient. But its really how much heating the design can tolerate. A continous plane will also help spread the heat.

It also looks as though you have current carrying capability on the ground, but not on the + side of the battery, those traces need to be wide if they are carrying 15A also.

Thanks for your feedback, as I mentioned I used inner traces as GND planes I separated two inner planes as fuel gauge and charger/load ground, should I also add power trace in inner planes? And the battery+ side is 200mil wide. There is not enough place for wider power planes so I thought increasing the thickness of traces would solve the problem.
